# OnClick event on different things like divs, img and so on then use data from those in controller to do something

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, view, controller

I been googling for about two hours and couldn't find anything about it.
What does one use(frameowork or maybe it is already uilt up in mvc) to pass data from VIEW to controller.

For example lets say I have a list of products and I wanna delete it without refreshing a page just by clicking on the thing like `<div data="23020id" onclick="doSomething()"></div>` and so if I would press on that div, something would happen in controller without refreshing the page.
I don't know how to google it or what should I've been aiming for here. 
I've seen that many websites does it but I don't really know what they use and how they do it.

Could someone give me any direction?

Comment: You can't just invoke some of the controllers methods - you have to perform HTTP request using AJAX.

Comment: What do you want to know exactly? how we can delete the record without refresh the page?

Comment: @Div yeah, It would help me get an idea how to do other stuff other than delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with your example.

> lets say I have a list of products and I wanna delete it without
>   refreshing a page just by clicking on the thing like 
>   `<div data="23020id" onclick="doSomething()"></div>`

Here it simply means you're calling javascript function `doSomething()` on click. But you can give `Id` to that div and perform click on that id.

```
<div id="test"data="23020id"></div>
```

*Now what could be in the this function?*

This function called your controller method via an ajax call, which will send `Id` to the controller which we need to delete.

javascript code:

```
$('#test').click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/controller/Delete",
        data:{Id:id},
        success: function(data) {
            // update some DOM element with the result returned by the
            // server. So supposing that you have some <div id="someContainer">
            // that will contain the part of the DOM you want updated:

        },
        error: function() {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

Now when you click on button, that will call your controller method and pass id.

```
public ActionResult Delete(int Id)
{
  // do delete here.
  return Json(data); 
}
```

Perform deletion on method and return view, and update it on ajax success.

I suggest you to use `Partial View` for such things. For more see here: [Rendering a Partial View and JSON Data Using AJAX in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/748842/Rendering-a-Partial-View-and-JSON-Data-Using-AJAX)

Comment: Thanks for long and detailed answer. I'm gonna experiment with it a bit now and will let you know how it goes. So, when it succes in the controller ActionResult Delete and return data without fail then I can modify things in succes: function(data). Correct?

Comment: Yeah, you will get data on `function(data)` and that you have to bind with your front end code.

Comment: One more thing, in place where you have: data:{Id:id} . lower case id is a id from a div and upper case Id is for overload?

Comment: Here `Id` indicates your action parameter `Delete(int Id)` and second `id` is id of record which you want to delete.

Comment: Tried to work on in but after pressing on the product it doesnt launch my controller at all, only keeps showing alert("success") in success:

Comment: Can you please create a new question and show your code, so we can help you!

Answer (score 1):

you can try with this

you can not return **View()** from ajax call. you need to retrun **Json()**

you Action method

```
public ActionResult Delete(int Id)
{
  // delete method call
  return Json("success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

your ajax call

```
$("#divId").click(function() {
  var dataattr = $(this).attr("data"); //use this variable 

 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/controller/Delete",
    data:{Id:dataattr },
    success: function(data) {
        refresh your DOM element
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("error");
    }
 });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you could use JQuery for that..

```
$("#divId").click(function() {
    dataattr = $(this).attr("data"); //use this variable 
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Yeah, but I want to know how to use it on server in mvc controller

Comment: simply start an ajax request with the dataattr variable

Comment: This answer doesn't really answer the question